# SlickGrid - Getting the Keyword Search Filter to Work

Tags: jquery, search, slickgrid

I'm trying to co-opt SlickGrid for a project I'm developing, and I'm starting by trying to recreate the out-of-the-box examples with nothing else customized other than the randomly generated data and the CSS. The only thing that's not working right now is the Search function. I would really appreciate it if some of you could take a look at my code and let me know if there's something I'm doing wrong. Here's the link: http://www.tomryandesign.com/dev/datagrid/custom2/

Answer (score 0):

Try this illustrative example.

```
var dataView = new Slick.Data.DataView();
var slickGrid = new Slick.Grid($('#grid_div'), dataView, gridColumns, gridOptions);
//Keyup event on search selector..
$('#search').keyup(function(e) {
 // clear on Esc
  if (e.which == 27) {
   this.value = "";
  }

  var searchList = $.trim(this.value.toLowerCase()).split(' ');
  dataView.setFilter(gridFilter);  
  slickGrid.invalidate();
  this.focus();

});
//This is custom logic for grid Filtering..
function gridFilter (rec) {
            var found;

            for (i = 0; i < gridSearchList.length; i += 1) {
                found = false;
                $.each(rec, function(obj, objValue) {
                    if (typeof objValue !== 'undefined' && objValue != null 
                    && objValue.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(gridSearchList[i]) != -1) {
                        found = true;
                        return false; //this breaks the $.each loop
                    }
                });
                if (!found) {
                    return false;
                }
            }

            return true;
        }
```

This should work for your requirement.

Good Luck.Niks

Comment: Hi Niks,I have a similar requirement could you please help me too. this is the link to my question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32463016/quick-filter-on-slick-grid

Answer (score 0):

In your trigger part, add this:

```
$('#search').keyup(function(e) {
    if(e.which === 27) {   // clear on esc
        this.value = '';    
    }

    dataView.setFilter(gridFilter);
    slickGrid.invalidate();
 });

**//create a function gridFilter**

function gridFilter (rec) {
        var found,
            searchData = $.trim($('#search').val()).toLowerCase().split(' ');
    for (i = 0; i < searchData.length; i += 1) {
        found = false;
        $.each(rec, function(obj, objValue) {       
        if (typeof objValue !== 'undefined' && objValue != null && objValue.toString().toLowerCase().indexOf(searchData[i]) != -1) {
            found = true;
            return false; //this breaks the $.each loop
        }
    });
    if (!found) {
        return false;
    }
  }
    return true;        
}
```